# Allow LDAP Authentication (or connection)

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to make a webapp that authenticate throw a LDAP Server. But i get this error:

```
ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
```

And when i try this command:

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h <host> -p 389 -D uid=myid,ou=all,ou=People,dc=utbvirtual,dc=edu,dc=co -x -w mypassword
```

I get this error:

```
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Checking with this web: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ It says:

> Open Port 389 is open on myip.

Trying to connect by telnet to the port:

```
> telnet ip 389
Trying ip...
Connected to ip.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any hints about what i have to do to allow connections with LDAP server?

--

Act:

Now i'm getting this error:

```
ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

But password and username are correct (and the DN also).

Comment: I have no knowledge of ldapwhoami nor much about linux, but have looked up on the linux.die.net on the command.. I am not sure if -vvv is a valid switch.. Though, the distinguishName looks a bit funky. Try this "ldapwhoami -vv -h <host> -p 389 -D cn=myid,ou=all,ou=people,dc=utbvirtual,dc=edu,dc=co -x -w mypassword"

Comment: Hi, @Lex. de distinguisName is correct, because is used that way in another app (moodle).

Comment: Also i tried with cn, and the same error appear.

Comment: The error is that your client cannot connect to the LDAP server. Is there a firewall? Can you telnet to port 389 from client to server?

Comment: telnet ip 389
Trying ip...
Connected to ip.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Problem solved. I was hashing the password before sending it to the ldap directory (docs say it was hashed). I send it without hashing and works correctly.

Comment: Please put your resolution to the answer, and have this closed off to help others who come across the same error. Glad its working for you, and how did you send it without hashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending the password hashed (because the ldap directory say it's stored like that). Later I tried sending the password without hashing and it works correctly.

Important: Check if DN is correctly builded.